# How to add legend below subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subplot

I am trying to add a legend below a 3-column subplot figure.

I have tried the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
ax[0].plot(data1)
ax[1].plot(data2)
ax[2].plot(data3)

ax_sub = plt.subplot(111)
box = ax_sub.get_position()
ax_sub.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + box.height * 0.1,box.width, box.height * 0.9])
ax_sub.legend(['A', 'B', 'C'],loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.3),fancybox=False, shadow=False, ncol=3)
plt.show()
```

However, this creates just one empty frame. When I comment out the ax_sub part, my subplots show up nice (but without a legend...)...

Many thanks!

This is closely related to [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)

Comment: What do you want to show in the legend? And where in the code do you specify that?

Comment: In this example it is the `['A', 'B', 'C']` in `ax_sub.legend()`.

Comment: I suppose the problem is that adding a `plt.subplot` does not work in a figure that is comprised of `plt.subplots`

Comment: No, that is not really a problem. My problem is to understand what you are trying to achieve here. Should the legend consist of a list of letters?

Comment: Since I provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317) to the linked question ("How to put the legend out of the plot") as well, I would be interested in how far it did not help you. Any suggestion on improving it?

Comment: really great answer thanks! Just did not have a chance to respond last night anymore...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The legend needs to know what it should show. By default it will take the labeled artist from the axes it is created in. Since here the axes `ax_sub` is empty, the legend will be empty as well.

The use of the `ax_sub` may anyways not make too much sense. We could instead use the middle axes (`ax[1]`) to place the legend. However, we still need all artists that should appear in the legend. For lines this is easy; one would supply a list of lines as handles to the `handles` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data1,data2,data3 = np.random.randn(3,12)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
l1, = ax[0].plot(data1)
l2, = ax[1].plot(data2)
l3, = ax[2].plot(data3)

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3, wspace=0.33)

ax[1].legend(handles = [l1,l2,l3] , labels=['A', 'B', 'C'],loc='upper center', 
             bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.2),fancybox=False, shadow=False, ncol=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: great! Do you by any chance know how to change label(tab-)spacing? I only know `labelspacing = XXX`, which only changes the linespacing of labels.

Comment: Do you mean [`columnspacing`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend)?

Comment: exactly! so the spacing between -A, -B, and -C in your example.

Comment: Does this work for even number subplots?